# Is the "this" pointer always const?

Tags: c++, constants, member, const-correctness, member-functions

Let `X` be a class with member function `f()`.

`this` is an implicit argument for `f()`, it is of type `X* const`.

Then, if `f() const` is a const member function, the type for the `this` pointer is now `const X* const`.

In both cases, it seems that the type for the `this` pointer is `const`. Why then is it allowed inside the function `f()` definition to modify any data member of class `X`? Shouldn't we always resort to `const_cast` as in

```
void X::f() {        
       const_cast <int&> (member) = 1;    
}
```

If `f() const` is const, then this is the way to do:

```
void X::f() const{        
       const_cast <int&> (member) = 1;    
}
```

(or you can also have member mutable)

But why is this working

```
void X::f() {  
       member = 1;    
}
```

Comment: And just to confuse things, back in the early days of C++ you **could** modify `this`; that was the mechanism for placing an object into a particular region of memory, now replaced by placement `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pointer is a rvalue. It cannot be assigned a value, so that this pointer is a const pointer does not matter.

If `f()` is a non const member function, this pointer points to non const `X`, so data member of X can be modified.

But if `f() const` is a const member function, this pointer points to const `const X`, so data member of X cannot be modified. Then, it need for data member to be mutable or to const_cast if one wants to modify it inside `f() const` definition.

We can do, for const_cast,

```
void X::f() const{        
       const_cast <int&> (member) = 1;    
}
```

If `member` is a reference to a non-const int, then assignment is accepted by compiler and have wanted behavior. If `member` is reference to a const int, behavior is not predictable. Compare these:

```
const int a = 10;
const int* b = &a;
int* c = const_cast<int*>(b);
// *c = 20;
```

c is a const_cast of a const int* whose pointee a is const. Behavior is undefined.

```
int a1 = 10;
const int* b1 = &a1;
int* c1 = const_cast<int*>(b1);
*c1 = 20;
```

c1 is a const_cast of a const int* whose pointee a is const. This is working, you can freely assign new value to int pointed by c1.

It is known that const member function cannot change value of data members. What we say her is that this is because then, this pointer's pointee is const.

Answer (score 3):

> `this` is implicit argument for `f()`, it is of type `X* const`.

Not quite (it's actually an *rvalue* of type `X*`), but close enough for the sake of this question.

> In both cases, it seems that type for this pointer is const. Why then is it allowed inside the function f() definition to modify any data member of class X ?

Because if the *pointer* is `const` (as in `X* const`), you can't change the *pointer*. You can change whatever it points to. If it's a pointer-to-const (as in `const X*`), then you can't change what it points to.

So you can never modify `this` itself; you can't write `this = &some_other_object`. In a `const` member function, you also can't modify the (non-mutable) members of `*this` without a dodgy `const_cast`.